# CMS для мобильного приложения?

Tags: php, mobile-development

В ходе разработки мобильного приложения встал вопрос о том, на чем делать бэкенд. Пока склоняемся к использованию Symfony, поскольку уже был опыт использования этого фреймворка и есть опыт написания на PHP. С каким конфигом лучше всего разворачивать сервер, что использовать для него, на чем писать бэк? Основная задача, которая нужна от бэкенд сервера, это обработка запросов от тысячи пользователей одновременно, а опыта разработки таких проектов у нашей команды еще не было. Со стороны пользователей планируется подгрузка данных по REST API, с админской части планируется управление этими данными.
Вероятно, вопрос очень абстрактный, но хотелось бы узнать какой опыт с этим был у других, а то пока не очень представляем с чего начать и какие подводные камни нас могут ожидать.

Answer (score 0):

> на чем писать бэк?

На самом деле это не имеет значения. Если Вы используете REST на бэке может быть любой технологический стек, который поддерживает работу с HTTP. PHP, NodeJs, Java, ASP.NET, Django, etc... В любом случае приложение будет только отправлять запрос на нужный адрес и получать на него ответ.

> Основная задача, которая нужна от бэкенд сервера, это обработка
>   запросов от тысячи пользователей одновременно

Успех в решении этой задачи зависит в первую очередь о того, как написан бэк, а вовсе не от того на чём он написан. Есть веб приложения на PHP, которые справляются с огромной нагрузкой. И встречаются случаи, когда на том же C# или Java люди получают дикие тормоза. Всё зависит от квалификации разработчика.

Единственное, говоря о производительности вы не учитываете ещё конфигурацию железа, которое придётся использовать. Этот вопрос также следует хорошо проработать, т.к. если сервера откровенно слабые, то это может свести на нет все усилия по оптимизации ПО.